# C# Curly brackets issue

Tags: c#, curly-braces

I'm following a tutorial on C# on making a text-based game and I ran into an issue right at the start. The following code:

```
namespace GameV2
{
    class Level
    {
        private static Room[,] rooms;

        #region Properties
        public static Room[,] Rooms
        {
            get { return rooms; }
        }
        #endregion


        public static void Initialize();
    *{*
    }

        private static *BuildLevel*();
    {
    }
        return false;


    }
*}*
```

gives me 3 errors.

> Error 1   Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>
> Error 2   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
>   Error 3   Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

The italics represent the errors in order. Fr some reason Visual c# express won't let me use { in a method definition, and pushes my final } out of the code box. Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: you shouldn't have ";" aftear each method prototype.

Comment: BuildLevel() has not return type either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You don't have semicolons after methods. You may be confusing them for C
  method prototypes.
- BuildLevel should have a return type.
- All statements have to be inside methods, you can only have declarations outside of methods

This should compile:

```
namespace GameV2
{
    class Level
    {
        private static Room[,] rooms;

        #region Properties
        public static Room[,] Rooms
        {
            get { return rooms; }
        }
        #endregion


        public static void Initialize()
        {
        }

        private static bool BuildLevel()
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void Initialize();

private static *BuildLevel*();
```

Those are *declarations*. They cannot be followed by `{ }`. Remove the `;` and it will work.

```
private static TYPEHERE *BuildLevel*();
```

This is missing a return type.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the two `;`

```
public static void Initialize()
{
}

private static BuildLevel()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Initialize();
{
}
```

should be

```
public static void Initialize()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolons from the end of your function declarations (before the opening curly brace).

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for the semicolons. You have semicolons between the method names and their bodies.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the problem:

```
private static *BuildLevel*();
    {
    }
        return false;
```

You didn't specify a return type, and the `return false;` should be inside the brackets.